# Bridged Network Interface to a Virtual Machine connected to a VPN

Tags: kvm, vpn, virt-manager

I'm currently running an Ubuntu server with a bridged network interface so I can run VMs with their own local IPs on my network. I use ExpressVPN and I'd like to connect a VM to this VPN but not actually use the ExpressVPN app or VPN configuration inside the VM due to the limited processing power of the VM resulting in internet speeds being less than ideal.

Instead I'd like the Ubuntu host machine to have a virtual network interface for the VM that is bridged to my local network (giving a local IP) and also connected to ExpressVPN (I assume through OVPN or L2TP, not Express' app) so all the VM's internet traffic is routed through the VPN without the VM having to do any of this processing.

The Ubuntu host however shouldn't be using the VPN for internet traffic, only the VM. Is this possible? Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Running Ubuntu 20.04, Virt Manager with a Windows 10 KVM

***More details:**

I have an ethernet connection (eno1) that a netplan virtual bridge (br0) is set up to supply a local IP (x.x.x.1) to the Ubuntu Host, the VM is connected to br0 also with a local IP (x.x.x.2). I believe I need to create a virtual interface on the host machine that is connected to ExpressVPN via OpenVPN (this is supported by them and avoids the use of their proprietary software) but doesn't route any internet traffic through it. Then connect the VM to this virtual interface so all the VM internet is routed through a VPN - still with access to the local network though.

Netplan configuration:

```
network:                                                                                                                  
ethernets:                                                                                                                
eno1:                                                                                                                     
dhcp4: false                                                                                                            
dhcp6: false                                                                                                        
bridges:                                                                                                                  
br0:                                                                                                                      
interfaces: [ eno1 ]                                                                                                    
addresses: [x.x.x.1/24]                                                                                             
gateway4: x.x.x.0                                                                                                   
mtu: 1500                                                                                                               
nameservers:                                                                                                              
addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]                                                                                          
parameters:                                                                                                               
stp: true                                                                                                               
forward-delay: 4                                                                                                      
dhcp4: no                                                                                                               
dhcp6: no                                                                                                           
version: 2
```

Comment: Looks like you are asking two quite different questions 1/ how to configure the VPN without using the proprietary tools provided by the supplier 2/ how to route adequately VM's traffic through this VPN. Then for the 2/ part, you'd have to give more information. Is an actual (physical) host interface used as bridge port here?  Supplying the current network resulting state when a VM is running would help 2/ . (I'd have no clue for part 1/ anyway).

Comment: @A.B ExpressVPN allows connections over OpenVPN or L2TP so no proprietary tools are needed for that part, no issues there. Apologies about part 2, you're correct I'll add some more information now. Thanks!

Comment: But if you're needing help for part 1/ then you should ask two different questions. Is part 1/ already configured?

Comment: Yes, I can already connect the host to the VPN using OpenVPN but this does what is intended for a regular VPN user and sends all the host's traffic through the VPN. I instead need help configuring the host to not send traffic through the VPN and instead bridge it to the VM so only the VM's traffic travels through the VPN